# Implicit loop in Perl

Tags: python, perl, for-loop

I'm trying to learn Perl, and I was wondering if there was a better equivalent to `map()` in the following code to generate a list of four integers (fake IP addresses):

```
map(int(rand(155) + 100), (0,0,0,0))
```

In Python I would do

```
[int(random.randrange(100, 255)) for _ in range(4)]
```

Although I'm fairly certain there is a better way to do that as well.

Comment: Using `map()` is perfect in this situation. You might want to replace the list `(0,0,0,0)` with a range `1..4` like the answer given by @ysth

Comment: For some reason, using 1..4 didn't work with `perl -e` when I was testing it. It kept claiming there was a compilation error after the semicolon at the end of the statement, but complied with the explicit list.

Comment: Weird, I just did the following (on Windows, Perl 5.10): `perl -e "print join '.', map 100 + int rand 155, 1..4"` - and printed `254.139.105.133`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An IPv4 address is just a 32-bit integer, so I'd use

```
unpack('C4', pack('N' int(rand(2**32))))
```

(This doesn't limit each octet to 100..255, but doing so makes no sense anyway.)

Be warned that the `rand` of some systems have less than 32-bits of entropy

```
>perl -V:randbits
randbits='15';
```

On those systems, it will be impossible for your code to return some IP addresses (no matter what technique you use) if you use `rand`. In the system in the example, only 32,768 of the 4,294,967,296 addresses can be returned by `rand`.

Libraries on CPAN provide random number generators with more entropy.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "IP-spec" addresses. Really just a list of four three-digit integers. How and why does pack/unpack work?

Comment: What's that??? IPv4 addresses are just a 32-bit numbers. The w,x,y,z in w.x.y.z represent the value each of each the four bytes of the IP address.

Comment: Just a list of numbers that could conceivably be IP addresses, or look like they could be. The only purpose was to generate a list of random numbers to feed into a more interesting program for display, entirely for educational purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I usually just do:

```
map 100 + int rand 155, 1..4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another notation, similar to your Python example, could be:

```
# assign each random octet to a list.
my @list;
push @list, int(rand(155) + 100) for (1 .. 4);
```

Usually questioners are using a for(each) translation approach and ask if there is a more elegant way, upon which map is suggested. My preference would be to stick to your map approach but instead of processing a list of four 0's, use the range `1 .. 4` exactly as ysth has shown, it is clearer what the code is doing this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to convert this based on what I think your Python code is doing.

```
my @ip = qw(0 0 0 0);   #create 4 member array
foreach my $number(@ip) {
    $number += int( rand(155) + 100 );
}
print "Your IP array is currently '@ip'\n";

my $ip_joined = join '.', @ip;     #create period separated string from the array
print "Your joined IP string is $ip_joined\n";
```

If you're really trying to minimize the number of the lines for some reason, you could trim that down to a single line foreach loop by taking out some of the pretty white space:

```
my @ip = qw(0 0 0 0);   #create 4 member array
foreach my $number(@ip) { $number += int(rand(155) + 100) }
```

Looking at it that way, it really does look like a map loop:

```
my @ip = qw(0 0 0 0);   #create 4 member array
@ip = map { int(rand(155) + 100) } @ip;
```

Also, the { } of map can be replaced with a simple comma between the map expression and the list it applies to:

```
my @ip = qw(0 0 0 0);   #create 4 member array
@ip = map int(rand(155) + 100), @ip;
```